# LaTeX - Change failed reference color

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, citing

Let's assume I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Good cross-reference: Table \ref{tab:good}

Bad cross-reference: Table  \ref{tab:bad}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{table}
  \label{tab:good}
\end{table}



Good citation: \cite{Knu86}

Bad citation: \cite{Knu86q898}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Two questions:

1) Can I change the color/font of the failed reference so that instead of 3 grey question marks it will show either 3 \Large question marks in a bold red font?

2) can I do the same for the failed citation?

I am hunting for failed refs/citations in my thesis and that would help a lot.

Thanks

**EDIT**

@campa 's patches work perfectly when using the MWE, yet when ran on my thesis, I get errors such as:

```
line 374: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xshowcmd' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. }

line 376: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xpretocmd' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. ...\xpatch_pretocmd:Nnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4} }

line 378: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xapptocmd' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. ...\xpatch_apptocmd:Nnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4} }

line 390: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xpatchcmd' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. }

line 403: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xshowbibmacro' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. }

line 408: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xpretobibmacro' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. }

line 413: LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\xapptobibmacro' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. }
```

Any idea what might be causing this? any package that might cause this? I use *biblatex* for library management.

**EDIT 2**

Using *regexpatch* instead of *xpatch* fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant commands are

```
% latex.ltx lines 4046-
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%  <======= HERE THE TWO QUESTION MARKS
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
```

for references, and

```
%latex.ltx lines 6316-
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}% <= HERE THE QUESTION MARK
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
```

for citations. You may patch them to replace the question mark(s)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
%Usage: \xpatchcmd{command}{search}{replace}{success}{failure}
\xpatchcmd{\@setref}{??}{\Large\textcolor{red}{???}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@citex}{?}{\Large\textcolor{red}{???}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Good cross-reference: Table \ref{tab:good}

Bad cross-reference: Table  \ref{tab:bad}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{table}
  \label{tab:good}
\end{table}



Good citation: \cite{Knu86}

Bad citation: \cite{Knu86q898}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Knu86} A book.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks! works like a charm on the MWE. However getting errors when running pdflatex on the thesis (see above update). Any idea?

Comment: It looks that using _regexpatch_ instead of  _xpatch_ fixed the issue :) . Could you please update your code with it so I can accept your answer? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. As you say, the answer solves the problem of the original question. You want me to adapt the answer to a problem which is _not_ present in the MWE: I don't believe that correspond to the site's policy.

Comment: Ok, let's leave it like this then, I added a line in the question commenting about it. Anyway, Many thanks! :)